# Can't get application made with google app engine to run

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html)

to create a to-do list app using Google App Engine. When I go to deploy it I get this error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
```

From looking at the output in the console it links to the following line in my code

```
EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
```

I have seen something similar on this site but there was no solution to it. Below are the classes that are related to the error

**Dao.Java**

```
public enum Dao {
INSTANCE;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Todo> listTodos() {

    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("select m from Todo m");
    List<Todo> todos = q.getResultList();
    return todos;
}

public void add(String userID, String summery, String description, String url) {

    synchronized(this) {

        EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
        Todo todo = new Todo( userID, summery, description, url );
        em.persist(todo);
        em.close();

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Todo> getTodo(String userID) {

    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager(); // Error links to here
    Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Todo t where t.author = :userID");
    q.setParameter("userID", userID);
    List<Todo> todos = q.getResultList();

    return todos;
}

public void remove(long id) {

    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();

    try {
        Todo todo = em.find(Todo.class, id);
        em.remove(todo);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
}
```

**EMFService.java**

```
public class EMFService {

private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

private EMFService() {}

public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
    return emfInstance;
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Console output**

```
WARNING: Nested in javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:        Could not initialize class com.chrismcnulty.gaetutorial.EMFService:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class      com.chrismcnulty.gaetutorial.EMFService
at com.chrismcnulty.gaetutorial.Dao.getTodo(Dao.java:35)
at org.apache.jsp.TodoApplication_jsp._jspService(TodoApplication_jsp.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:106)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: it was weird. i did same way with you but no problem. check your include jar maybe?

Comment: Everything seems to be there unless I am missing another jar file that is not included with the sdk download

Comment: Should I have anything else in my build path other than the App Engine sdk and jre system library?

Comment: App Engine SDK and jre System library should be enough. i try change my Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-xxx"); with wrong keyword and got same error with you but also got     No persistence providers available for "transactions-xxx"

Comment: This is such an annoying error. The farthest I can get is to the login stage but when I hit login I am shown the error again

Answer (score 0):

This is likely actually cased by it not being able to initialize the EMFService class.  static members are initialized when the class is loaded.  The line that's actually failing is this:

`private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");`

Is "transactions-optional" maybe wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've checked the spelling a few times and copied it from the persistence xml file, as that is the persistence unit used.

Comment: I've just been looking at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview) and the code I have is identical to the one on the documentation page.

Comment: I've added the console output

Comment: because of the way that classes get loaded I would suggest moving this: `emfInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");` into the get method temporarily just to see what exception you get then.  When a static member fails to initialize you get some very unhelpful errors from Java.

Comment: It returns the same thing unfortunatly

Comment: you need to get down to the real reason that createEntityManagerFactory is failing.  The exception your getting is hiding the real exception.  Something like this:  `public class EMFService {

private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = null;

private EMFService() {}

public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
    efmInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");return emfInstance;
}
}`

Comment: I have tried that, but I am still getting the same output that I have posted above.